# Remove OS X, install Windows 8 (w/o Superdrive or USB-boot)

Tags: macos, windows-8, usb, macbook-pro

At the moment, I'm running Windows 8 on it's own hard drive (5400 RPM - OLD) which was replaced with the standard Superdrive (DVD-drive) a while back. The problems first occoured when I realized that my MacBook Pro 2010 edition didn't support booting via USB, meaning that:

I couldn't install Windows 8 on my "new" (old) hard drive because I replaced the Superdrive with it (the hard drive), and the Mac didn't support USB booting, so I ended up following this tutorial: http://huguesval.com/blog/2012/02/installing-windows-7-on-a-mac-without-superdrive-with-virtualbox/

OK - now to the actual question. Since I have two hard drives in my MacBook;
1x 128GB SSD  - running OS X
1X 500GB 5400RPM HDD  - running Windows 8

I would like to remove OS X from the SSD, transfer my current Windows 8 (as an image?) installation from the 500GB HDD over to the (then) formatted and clean SSD, install Windows 8 on it, and remove Windows 8 from the (then) redundant 500GB HDD, and use that as a storage drive instead.

Now, that's a huge task! So my actual question here would be, I guess, how on Earth should this be done? Any ideas at all?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't move Windows as image because it would not fit into that SSD and that is not how it should be done.

If I was in your place I would save my data from OSX to windows HDD. Then I would do a clean Windows install on SSD. After that you can put back your data from old HDD to new installation on SSD.

Then, you can do whatever you want with your HDD, format it, make more partitions, install OSX on one of them or whatever else you want to.